# Documents associated by location

Tags: document

We have 400 buildings and 5000 different chemical data PDF documents. Each building can have some of the chemical data PDF documents associated with them. Is there a way to have 2 lists 1 for buildings and 1 for all the chemical data PDFs. The when I sort by building I can see all the chemical data PDFs associated with each building.  Example building 1 has 30 chemical data sheets and do on.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure, if I got your question, but I think you should have look at lookup columns:

You can create a list for your buildings, having one column 'building' and as many other columns as you like.
Create a document library. Add a new column of type 'lookup' with reference to the column 'building' of your buildings list.
When you add a new document (chemical data PDF) to the library you have to define a building and can choose from all buildings in your buildings list.
If you click on the column header of the lookup column in your document library containing the building, you can sort or filter the documents by values.

Instead of having a list for your buildings on the website, you can alternatively a term set in the term store of the Managed Metadata Service Application. And instead of adding a lookup column to your document library, you can add a column of type managed metadata. Sorting or filtering the contents of your document library is the same.